# UK visa date change

Tags: visas, uk

I have applied for a UK business visa with travel dates as 30th Oct - 5th Nov 2017. I have submitted the form and made the payment online. My travel dates have changed to a month later. I still have to go for my interview to VFS. Can my travel dates be changed on the form? At VFS?

Comment: I wouldn't mention it. If the officer at the border asks you, you can say the dates changed.